# How to define subgroups of finitely presented groups in GAP?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap

As an example, suppose I define `D := DihedralGroup(8);` I then use `H := Image(IsomorphismFpGroup(D));` to get a finitely presented form of the group. GAP prints out the generators `[F1,F2,F3]`. Next I want to define the subgroup `K := Subgroup(H, F2^2);` After I enter this command I get an error

```
Error, Variable: 'F2' must have a value
not in any function at line 3 of *stdin*
```

Is there a correct way to define subgroups in GAP? I have noticed the subgroup command works for symmetric groups.

Answer (score 3):

The following command should work:

`K:=Subgroup(H,[H.2^2]);`

Explanation:

- $\text{H.2}$ returns the second generator of $\text{H}$, which is the element $\text{F2}$ of $\text{H}$.$\\[2pt]$

  The first argument to the **Subgroup** command is the parent group.$\\[2pt]$

  The second argument to the **Subgroup** command is a *list* of generators, which explains the presence of the square brackets.